# BIG QUERY Error: Partitioning by expressions of type FLOAT64 is not allowed at [5:70]

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing a issue. Basically, i want to delete all duplicate rows, i did it successfully in a few tables. But there is a table that contains FLOAT column which is REVENUE. It show this error:

> Error: Partitioning by expressions of type FLOAT64 is not allowed at
>   [5:70]
>   Here are my codes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `pops-204909.monthly_reports.top_20_countries_revenue` AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CMS_ID, DATE,COUNTRY_NAME,REVENUE ORDER BY DATE  ) rn
  FROM `pops-204909.monthly_reports.top_20_countries_revenue`
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that you actually need `REVENUE` in the columns for partition, you need to convert into a string.

Usually this is a mistake, and partitioning only by `CMS_ID` should be fine.

> CAST(REVENUE as STRING)

Comment: CMS_ID is repeated montly therefore i gotta use other columns in PARTITION.

Comment: Side note: storing revenue as a `NUMERIC` type is probably a better idea, since you won't have issues with precision loss as you would with `FLOAT64`. You can also use `NUMERIC` inside `PARTITION BY`.